# Unable to handle(Keypress) modifier keys in android studio's emulator

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext, keyboard-events

I have an EditView in which I have set the below OnKeyListener to record the ctrl + left arrow key and ctrl + right arrow key.

```
        val MyKeyListener: View.OnKeyListener

    MyKeyListener = object : View.OnKeyListener {

        override fun onKey (v: View?, keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean
        {
            if (event?.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) {

                     Log.d ("Key", "left arrow")

                     if (event.isCtrlPressed) {

                         Log.d ("Key", "cntl + left")
                         return true
                     }

                } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT) {

                     Log.d ("Key", "right arrow")

                    if (event.isCtrlPressed) {

                        Log.d ("Key", "cntl + right")
                        return true
                    }
                } 
            }
            return false
        }

    }
    textfeild.setOnKeyListener(MyKeyListener)
```

I'm able to get only the left/right arrow click log i.e. if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) is true but not able to get (ctrl + left)/(ctrl + right) log.

The Android docs also specify the same way to handle modifier keys: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/keyboard-input/commands#ModifierKey

but it's doesn't seem to be working in my case, could anyone tell me why and what's the solution to handle modifier keys?

(I have also tried the same thing with event.isShiftPressed, but it's again not working)